# Get the path when run from terminal or command line

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that will be run from terminal or command line. You will have to supply a file name in the arguments. I want it to be able to get the path in which the program was run and then append the file name to it. It would be something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    if (args.length > 0) {
        if (args[0] instanceof String && !args[0].equals(null)) {
            if (args[0].equals("compile")) {
                System.out.println("File to compile:");
                String fileName = scanner.next();
                String path = /*get the path here*/ + fileName;
                File textfile = new File(path);
                if (textfile.exists()) {
                    Compiler compiler = new Compiler(textfile);
                    compiler.compile();
                } else {
                    System.out.println("File doesn't exist");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If the file name does not start with "<DRIVELETTER>://" or "/" (for Windows and Unix respectively), Java will automatically use relative paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
    Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString()
```

You can test by:

```
System.out.println("" + Paths.get("").toAbsolutePath().toString());
```

Comment: Sorry if I didn't explain it well enough, but I want to be able to get the path if any end user runs it from any directory. I need to be able be able to get where the user has cd to when the program was run through terminal/cmd.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + fileName;
```

Comment: But keep in mind that the path can be given absolute (e.g. '/bla/bla&filename')

Answer (score 0):

If i understand you correctly you are trying to get the path where the program is located.

if so you can try the following:

```
URI path = new File(MyClass.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().getPath().toURI());
```

Answer (score 0):

Replacing `/*get the path here*/` with `Paths.get(".")` should get you what you want.  If your argument is a filename in the same directory you don't have to provide a path to it to create the File object.

So in your case,

```
File textfile = new File(fileName);
```

should work as well.